# Work from a spontaneous endothermic reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, enthalpy, entropy

Some reactions are spontaneous ($\Delta_\mathrm{r}G < 0$) although they are endothermic ($\Delta_\mathrm{r}H > 0$), e.g. the plastic packs that once cracked they get cold.

I saw that it is often this spontaneous endothermic reaction taking place here
$$\ce{NH4NO3(s) –>[H2O] NH4+(aq) + NO3-(aq)} \tag{1} $$
more exactly, because of  $\Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\circ = \Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ - T\Delta_\mathrm{r}S^\circ$ this reaction will only be spontaneous at high temperatures.

So my question is: given the above exergonic reaction starting in standard conditions and a high enough temperature, could I extract work from this reaction while it reaches equilibrium?

In other words, in $\Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\circ = \Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ - T\Delta_\mathrm{r}S^\circ$ only the term $T\Delta_\mathrm{r}S^\circ$ contributes to the Gibbs free energy. Can we get work with this part only, or is it simply an indicator of the direction of the reaction? If the answer is yes, then how? For example, could I somehow get an electrode potential in a suitable electrochemical cell? And if not, is $\Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\circ$ simply an indicator of the direction of the reaction, but no “real” energy?

Does it all has anything to do with the fact that if we create a cold spot in a hot place, there is going to be kinetic energy transferred to the system due to warm air filling the hole?  Or see in the Carnot heat engine, one can increase the efficiency by reducing the temperature of the cold bar…

Comment: The reaction of NaHCO3 in an acidic solution of HCl is endothermic and it produces a gas that can produce work.

Comment: Cool! I guess that answers my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Even without volume work, the work can be done converting part of heat flow from neighbourhood to the system to work, e.g. by thermocouples or Stirling engine.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! This was very helpful.

Comment: @Buck Thorn, yes I did, its just that on my screen (chrome on an Imac)  $\circ$ is so small it is almost a dot, I cannot tell if its roman or italic or o or 0. I actually don't mind what it is just that it be bigger so that it looks sensible!

Comment: @porphyrin If it's any comfort  o or 0 are *rendered* almost identically on my system (0 is a tad bigger but lacks anisotropy which is somewhat bizarre). There are certainly many possible solutions but I find copy pasting into another editor as necessary to check suffices.